# Buttons to appear around click position of mouse

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a simple WPF app in which one of the core features would be that wherever the user clicks on the grid inside the main window, a number of buttons should appear around the position of the click. 
Now, I try to achieve this with only 1 button. I know that I have to capture the current position of the mouse and then modify the 4 arguments of the Margin of the button (left, top, right, bottom) by creating new instances of Thickness-es.

I managed to create new Thickness-es to the Margins, with the left and top argument set to the mouse X and Y cordinates respectively, but I don't know how to calculate or what to use as the right, and bottom arguments of the newly created Margins.
Here is the relevant function from the xaml.cs (the values in question are indicated as 0-s and *grid* is intented to refer to the grid):

```
private void Grid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var mouseLocation = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(grid));
            RandomButton.Margin = new Thickness(mouseLocation.X, mouseLocation.Y, 0, 0);
        }
```

Here is the relevant part of the xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
   <Button
     Name="RandomButton"
     Height="30"
     Width="30"
     Background="#FF130889"
     Click="RandomButton_Click"
     Content="RandomContent" />
</StackPanel>
```

It is also worth mentioning that when the button's HorizontalAlignment is set to Left and the VerticalAlignment is set to top, the button seem to do what I want with this setup, but only, when the windowsize is full.

I think I have to use the actual height of the window or the grid, but I don't know how. I know it is something simple, but I just started working with WPF, so I apreciate any kind of help!

Comment: First of all replace your stackpanel with a grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem is in determining the click relative position.
In this case you can use [Mouse.GetPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.getposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Here is the example with `Canvas`:

```
        private void SetPos()
        {
            var relativePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this.MainCanvas);
            Canvas.SetLeft(this.btn1, relativePosition.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(this.btn1, relativePosition.Y);
            btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

Comment: Thank You! Works like charm!